# Turn off console.log inside the scope of a function

Tags: javascript

I am writing code in modules, and each module can be debugged individually. I want to turn on or off `console.log` messages on a module level, to focus on just the module I'm working on.

I could have a `_debug_` variable for each module set to `true` or `false`, and write log messages like

```
if(_debug_) {
   console.log('The is a debug message.');
}
```

I find this approach a little cumbersome. Can I do better?

Comment: [Here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) is the console API for Firebug. It's probably different in Chrome and IE.

Comment: you should have your own function that prints out or not to console.out. put it to module and you can have much better control over it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hijack the `console` object upon entering the module scope if you want to disable debug statements. Here's a simple way to generate a substitute "console" object:

```
function noopConsole()
{
    var konsol = {};
    function noop(){}

    for (var k in window.console)
    {
        konsol[k] = noop;
    }

    return konsol;
}
```

Then, at the beginning of the module:

```
var console = _debug_ ? window.console || noopConsole();
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `console` in modules in which you want to deactivate logging.

Module without logging:

```
var console = {log: function(){}}
```

This assumes that each module is in its own scope.

Comment: Actually, there is a problem with this approach. What if in the module I'm also using `console.info`, `console.assert`, etc. I'm loosing those precious functions!

Comment: @Randomblue yes, looks like Matts approach is better.